# Prevent Enter from selecting a single item in a list box

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a multi-select list box. I want to be able to select a number of items and act on the selection by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. The problem I'm having is that when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the current item at the cursor becomes the only item selected. The others are deselected so my function only acts on a single item.
What can I do to prevent the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from selecting an item?

I am setting up the `onkeypress` function in JavaScript as follows. The `doListKeyPress` checks for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and acts on it.

```
select.onkeypress = function(e) { doListKeyPress(e, "myListName"); };
```

Comment: @seppy: The common behavior by a user for multi-select is via ctrl+click or ctrl-spacebar. `Enter` key is rather odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this event:

```
select.onkeydown = function(e) { if(e.keyCode == 13) select.blur(); };
```

As `keydown` comes before `keypress`, it will set the focus away from the listbox hence the default browser `Enter` behavior is 'bypassed'.

**Disclaimer:**
This answer does not allow selection of item by Enter. It can be done with further implementation though.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.
The onkeydown function successfully prevents the Enter key from selecting a single option. However, since the select is blurred on the key down stroke the onkeypress event never gets fired, so I had to create a document.onkeypress function to handle it as follows.
    document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            doListKeyPress(e, select);
        }
    };

Comment: @seppy, so you got what you want eventually?